# Extract a file from a zip archive then rename it

Tags: php

I have this file that gets downloaded at:

```
DownloadFile($reportDownloadUrl, $DownloadPath);
```

But it's a zip file. Inside of it, a CSV file gets created with a random name i.e `random_name.csv`

How do I extract this folder `abc.zip` in php and rename this file with random name to `new_name.csv`

Problem is that I can't use

```
$zip->renameName('currentname.csv','newname.csv');
```

since I don't have `currentname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code inspects the file in `zipLocation` then iterates over them to check if there are csv files. If it finds something it copies inside the directory with its original name, then copies another copy with a new name.

```
$zipLocation = "path/to/file.zip";

$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open($zipLocation) === true) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
        if (pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=="csv"){
            $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
            copy("zip://".$zipLocation."#".$filename, "./newname.csv");
            copy("zip://".$zipLocation."#".$filename, "./".$fileinfo['basename']);
        }
    }                   
    $zip->close();                   
}
```